# use a variable value within a selector on Richfaces JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I'd like to implement a cursor position when an input field inside a form is in error, on a RichFaces 4 project.

I have already used a JQuery function in the same form to focus on the first input field when the form is shown ; this works fine, every time I display the form the focus is on the first input field.

```
<rich:jQuery query="focus().select()" selector="#ESUserEditPanelGrid :input:visible:enabled:first" name="focusFirst"/>
<rich:popupPanel id="ESUserEditPanel" autosized="false" keepVisualState="false" domElementAttachment="parent"
                     width="800" height="400" headerClass="panel-header-class" resizeable="true" onshow="focusFirst();" >
```

To achieve my aim I try change the selector keyword with a bean method, but it doesn't work.

```
<rich:jQuery query="focus().select()" selector="#{eSUser.focus}" name="focusFirst"/>
```

The method getFocus() seems not to be called when the form is shown.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it like this:

```
<rich:jQuery query="focus().select()" name="focusFirst"/>
<rich:popupPanel id="ESUserEditPanel" autosized="false" keepVisualState="false"   
    domElementAttachment="parent" width="800" height="400" 
    headerClass="panel-header-class" resizeable="true" 
    onshow="focusFirst(#{rich:jQuery(eSUser.focus)},{})" >
```

This should work fine. The `#{rich:jQuery(eSUser.focus)}` command will get your component id from the bean and evaluate the proper jQuery object. This will be passed through to the named jQuery function `<rich:jQuery query="focus().select()" name="focusFirst"/>` which will execute the focus query.

I know I'm a little bit late but maybe someone in the future will have same issues too :)

Kind Regards,
exor298